# how to debug gitlab-ce docker container?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gitlab, gitlab-ce

My environment:
osx14.0
rubymine
gitlab-ce 16.4

I want to debug gitlab-ce remotelly with local rubymine on my mac.
I expose 3000 in the docker container, but rubymine cannot debug it on 3000 port directly.
I am more familiar to Java and PHP, but new to ruby
thanks!

I tried to use rubymine connect to 3000 port on the docker container, but I failed